# Difference between viewDidLoad and loadView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios5, viewdidload, loadview

Two objective-c methods, -(void) viewDidLoad and -(void)loadView are methods called upon execution of a program but whats the different between them?

Comment: The UIViewController Class Reference explains this very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean `viewDidLoad` and `loadView`? `viewDidLoad` is a method called when your view has been fully loaded. That means all your IBOutlets are connected and you can make changes to labels, text fields, etc.

`loadView` is a method called if you're (typically) not loading from a nib. You can use this method to set up your view controller's view completely in code and avoid interface builder altogether.

You'll typically want to avoid `loadView` and stick to `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Use -(void)loadView when you create the view. Typically usage is:

```
-(void)loadView {
    UIView *justCreatedView = <Create view>;
    self.view = justCreatedView;
}
```

Use -(void)viewDidLoad when you customize the appearance of view. Exapmle:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking about `loadView` and `viewDidLoad`.

`loadView` is a method that you not using a nib file - you use it to programmatically 'write' your interface

`viewDidLoad` fires automatically when the view is fully loaded. you can then start interacting with it.

more to read read in the discussion here [iPhone SDK: what is the difference between loadView and viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573958/iphone-sdk-what-is-the-difference-between-loadview-and-viewdidload)