# loadview method is called several times

Tags: ios

I create my views programmatically. If I do not put `loadView` method, the app runs well. However, When I add `loadView` method like this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loadView is called");
}
```

I found this method was called many times! At last, the app crashed.

I wonder why `loadView` method is called so many time.

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this all you have in your `loadView` method? Where is the code that calls this method?

Comment: are you calling self.view in init method or something?

Comment: I did use self.view in ViewDidLoad method:  [self.view addSubview:self.textField];

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573958/iphone-sdk-what-is-the-difference-between-loadview-and-viewdidload you seem to have infinite recursion because you are calling `self.view` from link - `"The self.view property accessor calls -loadView if the view isn't currently loaded"`

Comment: The self.view isn't allocated yet so it goes to loadView then goes back to viewDIdload which inturns calls again the loadView function. did I explain that clearly? something like loadview -> viewDidLoad->loadview based on the implemntation you are currently doing

Comment: @Joshua I was hoping you would give it as an answer as you were spot on.

Comment: @Popeye I was about to do it but jrturton beat me to it. atleast I hope I explained it somehow

Comment: The link you shared answered my question very well. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`loadView` is expected to, at some point, populate the `view` property of a view controller. The view property is lazily loaded (look at the call stack, you will see a method called something like `_loadViewIfNeeded`).

If `loadView` doesn't create a view, then each time the `.view` property is accessed, the view controller will call `loadView` again, trying to lazily load the view. At some point everything will go wrong because a view controller needs a view. If you access self.view from *within* your custom loadView, you'll get an infinite loop.

From the documentation:

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, **assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property**. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I used self.view in ViewDidLoad method. :)

Comment: It would have been nice to have seen that in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your load view are you calling `[self loadView]` rather than `[super loadView]`

Comment: Nop, I didn't call [super loadView]. Maybe the reason is I used self.view in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling loadView at all. https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView for reference

Comment: Why not Joshua? Direct quote from your Apple link "If you cannot define your views in a storyboard or a nib file, override the loadView method to manually instantiate a view hierarchy and assign it to the view property."

Comment: i use only coding part (with out xib and story board) in ViewDidLoad we can use self.view it will never create an issue.

Comment: @matt what i mean is you do not directly call it like [self loadview] let the viewController handle the call and just override the loadview to setup the current view. hope it makes sense