# How can I initialize a variable for UIViewController class in right syntax?

Tags: swift

I have a class called **UIViewControllerModel** which I like to initialize backgroundColor for this class, I am sure this a syntax error, need help for correction please.

```
class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {
    
    var backgroundColor: UIColor 

    required init(backgroundColor: UIColor) {

        super.init()
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
 
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: updated on top.

Comment: Side comment: please see [ask]. Especially the part where it says in bold: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.". Images of text are not searchable.

Comment: thanks, I was carful about codes, but I did know about errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required initializer is not the right one -- because your class is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you need a `required init?(coder: NSCoder)`. You can put your custom initializer that sets `backgroundColor` in separate `init`.

Also, instead of `viewDidLoad`, use `loadView` for your custom View Controllers that you make in code. This is how you do it:

```
class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {
    
    var backgroundColor: UIColor

    /// Put your custom argument labels here, not inside the `required init?`
    init(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    /// This is in case the View Controller is loaded from the Storyboard
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    /// Use this instead of viewDidLoad
    override func loadView() {
        
        /**
         Instantiate the base `view`.
         */
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        
    }

}
```

```
let modelVC = UIViewControllerModel(backgroundColor: UIColor.blue)
self.present(modelVC, animated: true)
```

Result:

[image: View controller with blue background presented]

Comment: could you please explain or update the answer why I should use **loadView** instead **viewDidLoad**? because both working same for me

Comment: @swiftPunk `loadView` actually *creates* the view. If you don't override it, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) says that a "plain UIView object" will be created instead. Although this is exactly what I did in with `view = UIView()`, you might need to change it to something else, like `view = UIImageView()`. Meanwhile `viewDidLoad` is called after the view is already created. That is mainly used when the view controller is loaded from the storyboard. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573968/14351818)

Comment: @aheze I'm doing the exact same thing as you, but I'm getting `Replace 'backgroundColor' with 'coder'`

Comment: @Jalil I just double checked and works fine for me. Maybe [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {

 var backgroundColor: UIColor 

 init(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
     self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
     super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

 }

 required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

 override func loadView() {

  self.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

 }

}
```